# Пагинация с помощью react-pager

Tags: reactjs, pagination

Добрый вечер. 
Вывожу ряд элементов, хочу сделать для них пагинацию с помощью react-pager. Пагинация работает и элементы выводятся, но они выводятся все, для них не работает ограничение. Подскажите, пожалуйста, где можно поставить ограничение для элементов (чтобы выгрузилось 4-5 картинок на страницу, а не 7), либо посоветуйте что-то альтернативное для пагинации в реакте, кроме react-pager.

Спасибо.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Pager from 'react-pager';


class AlbumsShow extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.renderImage = this.renderImage.bind(this);
     this.handlePageChanged = this.handlePageChanged.bind(this);

     this.state = {
            total:       3,
            current:     1,
            visiblePage: 2,
        };
   }

  handlePageChanged(newPage) {
        this.setState({ current : newPage });
    }

   renderImage(){
         return this.props.images.map(image => (
            <li key={image.id}>
                <img className="album_img" alt="job" src={image.img} />
                <p className="album_title">Test</p>
            </li>
        ));
    }

    render(){
        return (
          <div>
            <div>
            {this.renderImage()}
            </div>
            <Pager
                total={this.state.total}
                current={this.state.current}
                visiblePages={this.state.visiblePage}
                titles={{ first: '<|', last: '>|' }}
                className="pagination-sm pull-right"
                onPageChanged={this.handlePageChanged}
            />
          </div>  
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
    return {
     images: state.main.albums[0].images,
    };
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(AlbumsShow);
```

Comment: Помимо этого консоль выдает ошибку: Accessing PropTypes via the main React package is deprecated. Use the prop-types package from npm instead.

Comment: Хм, 64 звезды последняя активность в репозитории 4 месяца назад, я бы поискал что понадежнее. Конкретного подсказать правда ничего подсказать не могу увы, можно поискать на гитахбчике.

Comment: На ворнинг - по большому счету плевать. Смысл в том что React вынес PropTypes в отдельный пакет (https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types) и теперь по феншую использовать PropTypes из этого пакета, а не как React.PropTypes. Пока от этого ничего не сломается но ворнинг намекает что когда будете переходить на новый реакт - сломается.

Comment: Соответственно ворнинг порожден в том числе и этим вашим react-pager

Comment: у меня к каждой странице должен быть url, например: album/1/page/1, я могу сделать это (теоретически) с помощью react-paginate, но там не самая лучшая документация.
react-pager выводит, если подкорректировать это:
this.props.images.slice((this.state.current-1), this.state.current * 4).map(....

но выводит странно, на первой странице 0 картинок. на второй - 4, на третьей - 8, то есть оно не заходит на новую страницу, а подгружает картинки.